# Appending a text at the end of bullet point

Tags: python, regex

I have a multiline string of the following form:

```
Front

(A) Text1.

(A) Text2.

(A) Text3.

(A) Text4.

(A) Text5.

End
```

Note that Text1, Text2 etc may contain line breaks. I wish to append the string  `END` after each of Text1, Text2 etc.

Let `c` denote the multiline string above. I tried to use regex `re.sub` to perform this:

`c = re.sub("\(A\)(.*?)\n\n\(A\)" , r"(A)\1 END\n\n(A)", c, flags=re.DOTALL)`

However, this only replaces every odd-numbered point. Here is the output:

```
Front

(A) Text1. END

(A) Text2.

(A) Text3. END

(A) Text4.

(A) Text5.

End
```

The last bullet point can be handled as an exception case. I'm more concerned with that only every other bullet point has  `END` appended at the end. I believe this is because when the second `(A)` is used as the endpoint of `re.sub`, Python excludes it from being a starting point.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Because you effectively remove and create the next `(A)` RegEx would identify, it misses every other one. Instead of a single expression on the whole file, you could iterate each line for when one begins with `(A)` and do a replace then.

Comment: @Dan There are line breaks in text of each bullet point. How can I ensure that I append the text at the end of the entire bullet point instead of the first line of the bullet point?

Comment: You put the "END" and newline *before* each `(A)` because it's guaranteed to be at the end of the prior bullet. Keep a counter so that you skip the very first one you encounter and only do the ones thereafter. For the last one you can just add "END" if you reach EOF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's regular expressions support *lookahead*, which is good for your use case:

`c = re.sub("\(A\)(.*?)\n\n(?=\(A\))" , r"(A)\1 END\n\n", c, flags=re.DOTALL)`

A lookahead, denoted by `(?=)`, matches the enclosed pattern but does not include it in the matched span (it is a zero-width match).

Sample:

```py
import re

c = """Front

(A) Text1.
Foo.
Bar.

(A) Text2.
Some extra text and a fake bullet (A)
More text

(A) Text3.

(A) Text4.

(A) Text5.

End"""

c = re.sub("\(A\)(.*?)\n\n(?=\(A\))" , r"(A)\1 END\n\n", c, flags=re.DOTALL)

print(c)
```

prints

```
Front

(A) Text1.
Foo.
Bar. END

(A) Text2.
Some extra text and a fake bullet (A)
More text END

(A) Text3. END

(A) Text4. END

(A) Text5.

End
```

Answer (score 1):

The **regex** that I used to select lines starting with `(A)`:

```
r"\(A\).*"
```

I then used a custom replacement function to return the original line + `" END"` at the end. 
Here is the code:

#### Code:

```
import re

c = """Front

(A) Text1.

(A) Text2.

(A) Text3.

(A) Text4.

(A) Text5.

End"""

def rep(m):
    return m.group(0) + " END"

c = re.sub(r"\(A\).*", repl=rep, string=c)

print(c)
```

#### Output:

```
Front

(A) Text1. END

(A) Text2. END

(A) Text3. END

(A) Text4. END

(A) Text5. END

End
```

Comment: This may not address the case in which `Text1` etc. contain newlines.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your regex pattern to use LookAhead and Lookbehind which are zero-width (i.e. do not consume characters) to get around your issue of:

> I believe this is because when the second (A) is used as the endpoint of re.sub"

```
c = re.sub("(?<=\(A\))(.*?)(?=\n\n\(A\)|\n\nEnd)" , r"\1 END", c, flags=re.DOTALL)

print(c)
```

**Output**

```
Front

(A) Text1. END

(A) Text2. END

(A) Text3. END

(A) Text4. END

(A) Text5. END

End
```